# Windows can resolve hostname via ping but Linux/OSX cannot

Tags: networking, dns, ping

I have an unknown device in my network that behaves weirdly and I'd appreciate some help on this topic.

Under my Windows machine I am able to ping the hostname `lmachine.0` and get the corresponding IP address (`192.168.18.64`). When I try to do an `nslookup` on this hostname from the Windows machine I get the error `Non-existent domain`.

With my Linux and OS X machine I cannot ping nor resolve the hostname `lmachine.0`. Pinging from those machines using the IP address (`192.168.18.64`) is working fine.

Here is the output of an `sudo nmap 192.168.18.64` scan:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-26 11:22 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.18.64
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1001/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 1E:30:6C:A2:45:5E (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.43 seconds
```

I'm now wondering what kind of hostname this `lmachine.0` is, since only Windows seems to be able to resolve it? And how can I resolve it on a UNIX OS?

Comment: You're not mentioning whether you have a DNS server in your network or not. I'd assume that you don't. Also, you don't mention whether you can ping the machine from Linux and OS X using its IP address. I presume you don. In this case, it's nothing but an unfortunarte entry in the Windows machine's `host` file. Which, of course, you could replicate manually to the Linux and OS X machines.

Comment: @ClassStacker Thank you for your input. I can (!) ping the machine using the IP address from Linux and OS X. The hosts file is empty on the Windows machine. Any other ideas?

Comment: ...are you seriously using `.0` as a DNS domain? o.0

Answer (score 1):

MS Windows uses a variety of naming services. DNS is only one of them.

One is [NetBIOS Naming Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#Name_service) - Some computers regularly broadcast their name and address and other computers on the same LAN will be able to receive and keep track of these names.

There are a variety of such protocols - Windows PCs and things that coexist with them are irritatingly chatty on a LAN:

[image]

Note the "Host Announcement" with "Periodicity" = 12 minutes.